# Why my shared prefs test does fail on null pointer?

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, junit

I have got MVVM / HILT project. I am trying to cover `sharedPrefsRepoImpl` with tests. For some reason when I mocking `edit` and trying to call `putString` it throws nullException and test fail.

Here is my class

```
class PrefsRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(private val sharedPref: SharedPreferences) : PrefsManager {

    override fun saveDataInPrefs(key: String, value: String) {
        with(sharedPref.edit()) {
            putString(key, value)
            apply()
        }
    }
```

Here is my test class

```
    class PrefsRepositoryImplTest {

    private lateinit var subject: PrefsRepositoryImpl
    private val sharedPreferences:SharedPreferences = mock()

    @Before
    fun setup(){
        subject = PrefsRepositoryImpl(sharedPreferences)
    }

    @Test
    fun saveDataInPrefs_success(){
        val mockEdit = mock(SharedPreferences.Editor::class.java)
        `when`(mockEdit.putString("testKey","testValue"))
            .thenReturn(mockEdit)
        subject.saveDataInPrefs("testKey","testValue")
        verify(mockEdit, times(1)).putString("testKey","testValue")

    }
}
```

So `mockEdit` works fine and i got it to use but here is error message

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mywebsite.todoapp.data.PrefsRepositoryImpl.saveDataInPrefs(PrefsRepositoryImpl.kt:21)
at com.mywebsite.todoapp.PrefsRepositoryImplTest.saveDataInPrefs_success(PrefsRepositoryImplTest.kt:40)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:119)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `val sharedPreferences:SharedPreferences = mock()` and passing it to the subject in the setup method, then you are setting completely a different `mockEdit` that has some answers to some methods, and you are NOT passing it to the subject, and then verifying that the `mockEdit` methods' must have been called.

The issue relies on the dependency being passed to the subject; it is not what you are stubbing methods answer on; what you need to do is the following:

```kotlin
class PrefsRepositoryImplTest {

    private lateinit var subject: PrefsRepositoryImpl
    private lateinit var sharedPreferences : SharedPreferences

    @Before
    fun setup(){
        val sharedPreferences = mock(SharedPreferences.Editor::class.java)
        subject = PrefsRepositoryImpl(sharedPreferences)
    }

    @Test
    fun saveDataInPrefs_success(){
        `when`(sharedPreferences.putString("testKey","testValue"))
            .thenReturn(sharedPreferences)
        subject.saveDataInPrefs("testKey","testValue")
        verify(mockEdit, times(1)).putString("testKey","testValue")

    }
}
```

We have deleted the `mockEdit`, and kept using the original `sharedPreferences` as a mock, but this time we initialize it in the setup, then we used it in the test.  Hope this will work for you!